# Unzipping a file zipped with python giving error "Unable to expand file.zip"

Tags: python, zip

Upon download of a file on our site, we zip up readme and tutorial files with it.  Upon download of **some** files, I am getting this error:

```
Unable to expand "File.zip" into "Downloads"
```

Code below. Any ideas why this might be happening on just some files and not others? Could it be related to the content in the files themselves?

```
if len(output_streams) > 1:
    # If we have multiple files, then package them up since we can only return one
    upload_name = file_key + '.zip'

    # Create a new stream and write to it
    write_stream = StringIO()

    zip_file = ZipFile(write_stream, "a")
    for ext_name, stream in output_streams.iteritems():
        if '.' in ext_name:
            zip_file.writestr(ext_name, stream.getvalue().encode('utf-8','ignore'))
        else:
            zip_file.writestr(file_key + '.' + ext_name, stream.getvalue().encode('utf-8','ignore'))

    #adding the readme file
    try:
        if 'ManufacturerName' in manuf['manufacturer']:
            zip_file.writestr('how-to-import.htm', "<script>window.location = 'https://www.example.com/manufacturer/';</script>")
        else:
            zip_file.writestr('how-to-import.htm', "<script>window.location = 'https://www.example.com/about/import/';</script>")
    except:
        zip_file.writestr('how-to-import.htm', "<script>window.location = 'https://www.example.com/about/import/';</script>")
    zip_file.close()
```

Comment: You bolded `some` like it has a meaning. So if you unzip **other** files you don't get the error?

Comment: That's correct. It only happens on 20% of the files.